# Snowflake child task not running after parent is suspended and child resumed

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a root task which starts at a specific time (ex. cron 15/5 6 * * * TZ) and continues running every 5 mins. It calls an SP which checks for certain criteria. Once all criteria is met, it suspends the root task and resumes the child task. But somehow the child task even after resuming is not running. I tried checking the docs but still didn't find any reason for child to be not running. Could someone help?

Also, The child task runs an SP which in turn resumes the root task and other dependent tasks (dependent on the child). But when I switch off the after clause in the child task def. and adds a schedule to run it, the SP which it calls resume the root task and sets it to run in the next 5 mins instead of setting the schedule for the next day, since current day's run is already suspended. Could anyone help on this too?

Answer (score 1):

have you used this?

-- enable recursive resumption of dependent tasks
select system$task_dependents_enable('');

Comment: The first child task is already being resumed in the stored procedure itself. While checking task_history it is showing started but it never gets started even after firing command "alter task TASK_T2 resume"

Comment: the option i provided above is needed to enable child tasks resuming, try it